# PHP redirect not working

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, download

this bit of code is not working. I am using PHP and want to redirect my user to CAD.HTML after he has submitted his data.
Am I missing something obvious here. Please help!

input name="Submit " type="submit" id="Submit " value="Submit Request" onClick="Location:cad.html"

I am beginner and haven't started writing functions please let me know if it is required with some bit of help with the code

Thank you

Update

form id="post" method='post' action="mymail.php" name="post"

input name="Submit " type="submit" id="Submit " value="Submit Request" onClick="location.href=cad.html" />

Comment: "I am using PHP and want to redirect my user to CAD.HTML" -- that example is using js, not PHP

Comment: You cannot reliably use JavaScript to redirect after a submit and there is absolutely no need. Redirect in the php only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="process.html" method="GET">
   ... your other inputs here ....

   <input name="Submit" type="submit" id="Submit " value="Submit Request" />
</form>
```

This is the proper way of creating a form in your html

In your php, you can process the data like

```
$variable = $_GET['name'];
```

and to redirect you can use the header function:

```
header('Location: cad.html');
```

This might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response Ibrahim but it didn't work. The page does not get redirected

Comment: ok i have made an edit now it should work, what are you trying to achieve? are you trying to send some information from one page to another?

Comment: Yes Ibrahim I am trying to collect user data send it to another page then redirect him to CAD.html ....I am using POST method

Comment: Missing quotes in the onclick. Using a submit to execute a location change is not a great idea either. Delete the first part of the answer and it is correct